# Dependent dropdown using json

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, dropdown

I am currently working on a dynamic dependent dropdown. I want a sidebar with each dropdown list depends on the one above it, so you based on what your selection is, the right data will show on the next selection. It should be Country -> Years -> Terms -> Movies. I don't know why my data won't retrieve data from the json file. I am new to programming so Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The Json file(moviessimple.js) format is like this:

```
  {
  "term": "2020W",
  "Year": 2018,
  "link": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6342440",
  "title": "Funan",
  "country": "France"
},
{
  "term": "2020W",
  "Year": 2017,
  "link": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6516966",
  "title": "And Then They Came for Us",
  "country": "United States"
},
{
  "term": "2020W",
  "Year": 2019,
  "link": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6751668",
  "title": "Parasite",
  "country": "South Korea"
},
```

Right now, my HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test2</title>
        <script src="CountryPoints.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="moviessimple.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br /><br />
        <div class="container">

            <div>
                <select name="country" id="country" class="form-control input-lg">
                    <option value="">Select country</option>
                </select>
                <br /><br />
                <select name="Year" id="Year" class="form-control input-lg">
                    <option value="">Select year</option>
                </select>
                <br /><br />
                <select name="title" id="title" class="form-control input-lg">
                    <option value="">Select movies</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    
     load_json_data('country');
    
     function load_json_data(country, Year)
     {
      var html_code = '';
      $.getJSON('moviessimple.js', function(data){
    
       html_code += '<option value="">Select '+country+'</option>';
       $.each(data, function(key, value){
        if(country == 'country')
        {
         if(value.Year == '')
         {
          html_code += '<option value="'+value.country+'">'+value.title+'</option>';
         }
        }
        else
        {
         if(value.Year == Year)
         {
          html_code += '<option value="'+value.country+'">'+value.title+'</option>';
         }
        }
       });
       $('#'+country).html(html_code);
      });
    
     }
    
     $(document).on('change', '#country', function(){
      var country_id = $(this).val();
      if(country_id != '')
      {
       load_json_data('Year', country_id);
      }
      else
      {
       $('#Year').html('<option value="">Select year</option>');
       $('#title').html('<option value="">Select movies</option>');
      }
     });
     $(document).on('change', '#Year', function(){
      var Year_id = $(this).val();
      if(Year_id != '')
      {
       load_json_data('title', Year_id);
      }
      else
      {
       $('#title').html('<option value="">Select movies</option>');
      }
     });
    });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is what you ave posted as moviessimple.js the whole content of this file or is there anything else. On the first glance it seems like that JSON file is not valid as it is missing an enclosing [ and ].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you only need to get the `data` from server once, save it to global variable then update the dropdown from other function

```js
var movieData = [];
var html_code = '';
load_json_data('country');

function load_json_data(country, Year) {
  /*
  // to apply in your page
  $.getJSON('moviessimple.js', function (data) {
    movieData = data;
    $.each(movieData, function (index, value) {
      html_code +=
        '<option value="' + value.country + '">' + value.country + '</option>';
    });
  });
  // and remove lines block below
  */
  movieData = [
    {
      term: '2020W',
      Year: 2018,
      link: 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6342440',
      title: 'Funan',
      country: 'France',
    },
    {
      term: '2020W',
      Year: 2017,
      link: 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6516966',
      title: 'And Then They Came for Us',
      country: 'United States',
    },
    {
      term: '2020W',
      Year: 2019,
      link: 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6751668',
      title: 'Parasite',
      country: 'South Korea',
    },
  ];
  $.each(movieData, function (index, value) {
    html_code +=
      '<option value="' + value.country + '">' + value.country + '</option>';
  });

  $('#country').append(html_code);
}

function updateDropdown(country, year, title) {
  if (!year) {
    html_code = '<option value="">Select year</option>';
    $.each(movieData, function (index, value) {
      if (value.country == country) {
        html_code +=
          '<option value="' + value.Year + '">' + value.Year + '</option>';
      }
    });
    // update year dropdown
    $('#Year').html(html_code);
    $('#title').html('<option value="">Select movies</option>');
  } else {
    html_code = '<option value="">Select movies</option>';
    $.each(movieData, function (index, value) {
      if (value.country == country) {
        html_code +=
          '<option value="' + value.title + '">' + value.title + '</option>';
      }
    });
    // update year dropdown
    $('#title').html(html_code);
  }
}

$('#country, #Year, #title').on('change', function () {
  if (this.id == 'country') {
    // reset year and title
    $('#Year').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
    $('#title').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
  } 
  
  if (this.id == 'title') {
    console.log('The title is: ' + $(this).val());
  } else {
    var country = $('#country').val();
    var year = $('#Year').val();
    var title = $('#title').val();
    updateDropdown(country, year, title);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div>
    <select name="country" id="country" class="form-control input-lg">
      <option value="">Select country</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
    <select name="Year" id="Year" class="form-control input-lg">
      <option value="">Select year</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
    <select name="title" id="title" class="form-control input-lg">
      <option value="">Select movies</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```